# Django template tag, python timezone aware dates different results

Tags: django

I have :

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

in my settings.py file. I am living in Istanbul/Turkey and there is one hour difference between Paris and Istanbul.

In the admin side when selecting a date, django correctly shows 1 hour difference. And using template tag i am getting the datetime i have set in the admin.

But when i pass the datetime via python using `beginning_date.strftime("%H:%M")`  python  substracts 1 hour from the value that was set via admin which is not true.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Django template defaultfilters to format your dates in Python code.

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import date as _date

_date(datetime_object, "%H:%M")
```

And, maybe related: Django cannot reliably use alternate time zones in a Windows. [See documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#time-zone).

Comment: I have used _date(datetime_object, "H:i")  in python code. But there still exists the extra 1 hour difference ?

Comment: Do you think it is related with my operating system's time settings. Maybe python's behaviour is true so  #Kevin's answer may be true...

Comment: No, if your on OSX, than it's not OS related. Try @KevinChristopherHenry answer. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime is correct. But django.template.defaultfilters isn't wrong: It handles datetime in templates: calling the same filter from Python should give you the same result. If this doesn't resolve your issue, than there might be something else wrong. Than read all the relevant docs and double check your settings. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Turkey has anything to do with it.

My guess is that the one-hour difference you're seeing is between the Paris timezone—which is being used, by default, to interpret and display dates—and UTC—which is being used to store the `datetime`, and which is the timezone of the `datetime` returned from the database.

If that's correct, then you can just use [`django.utils.timezone.localtime`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime) to convert the `datetime` to the current time zone (which by default will be `TIME_ZONE`):

```
localtime(beginning_date).strftime("%H:%M")
```